# How to get AWS workflow details

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm wondering how can you get the details from aws workflow details page. For instance, I'm trying to get start time for a workflow I'm running but I can't find the method in aws's api to get this. Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
import logging
import pip
import os
import email.utils
import datetime
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
import boto3
from configparser import ConfigParser


glue_client = boto3.client('glue')

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,['WORKFLOW_NAME','WORKFLOW_RUN_ID'])
workflow_name = str(args['WORKFLOW_NAME'])   
workflow_run_id = str(args['WORKFLOW_RUN_ID'])  
workflow_start_time = str(args['WORKFLOW_START_TIME']) 
print(workflow_start_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_workflow).

Example:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('glue')

response = client.get_workflow(
    Name='workflow_name',
    IncludeGraph=False
)
```